# Example of $GL(n, \Bbb F)$ that is not a lie group?

Tags: group-theory

For some field, $\Bbb F$, which may or may not be finite, is there an example of $GL(n,\Bbb F)$ that is not a lie group (ie isomorphic to a lie group as an abstract group)?  I know there must be one, but I can't seem to think of any off the top of my head.

This question came about after thinking a bit about challenge 8 of DARPA's math challenges:  http://www.math.utk.edu/~vasili/refs/darpa07.MathChallenges.html

Comment: As in like finite fields?

Comment: You need to specify the topology on this group for the question to make sense. You do you mean not isomorphic to a Lie group as an abstract group?

Comment: You make a good point, Moishe.  Let me edit the question...

Comment: If $F$ has cardinal larger than that of $\mathbb R$, then $GL(1,F)$ is not a Lie group in any way, provided we define manifolds to be separable, simply because its cardinal is larger than that of a manifold.

Comment: I wasn't even thinking about $\vert \Bbb F \vert \gt  \vert \Bbb R  \vert$.  Good one, Mariano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, Lie groups are smooth manifolds, therefore locally homeomorphic to some $\Bbb R ^n$. As soon as $\Bbb F$ has characteristic $p$, for instance, you no longer get such homeomorphisms.

Comment: For this to make sense you have to specify the topology on $GL(n,F)$. For instance, with discrete topology, it will be a zero-dimensional Lie group as long as $F$ is (at most) countable, e.g. for finite fields.

Comment: @MoisheCohen: True that, but I believe that the OP dind't have $0$-dimensional Lie groups in mind when he asked the question.